# python unique values in a list of tuples where one of the elements is an list

Tags: python, list

Say I have an list list of tuples like this:

```
a = [(["I", "love", "apples"], "good"),
(["I", "love", "apples"], "good")),
(["I", "hate", "apples"], "bad")),
(["I", "dislike", "apples"], "bad")),]
```

I want to remove duplicated, but `list(set(a))`errors out:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is there any pythonic way to remove duplicates from this type of list

Comment: While the above link is slightly different, the solution will work in this case too (with minor tweaks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are creating the data, use tuples as the first item instead of lists

```
a = [
    (("I", "love", "apples"), "good"),
    (("I", "love", "apples"), "good"),
    (("I", "hate", "apples"), "bad"),
    (("I", "dislike", "apples"), "bad")
]

print len(set(a))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

lists are not hashable so you can not simple call set on a.

you can convert the inner lists to tuples, then call list(set()):

```
list(set([(tuple(sent), good_bad) for sent, good_bad in a]))
```